# CSS dropdown menue Navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation bar with 5 elements. two of them have an additional dropdown menu, which should be displayed on mouse hover. The problem is the background I make when mouse hover cover the title of the dropdown menu and font color supposed to be white inside green background.

here are the html and CSS I have implemented:

```css
.nav {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left; /* change to "center" or "right" to align differently */
  border-bottom: 10px solid green; /* bottom border */
  background: #ffffff;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%, #d8d8d8 100%); 
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-     stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#d8d8d8));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#d8d8d8 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#d8d8d8 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#d8d8d8 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ffffff 0%,#d8d8d8 100%);
 }
.nav ul li{
  display: inline-block;vertical-align:top;
  }
.nav ul a{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: black; /* font color */
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  font-size: 14px; /* font size */
  font-weight: bold;
  vertical-align: bottom;
 -webkit-transition: color 0.5s; /* transition property and duration */
 -moz-transition: color 0.5s;
 transition: color 0.5s;
 }

ul .nav a::before{
 content: '';
 color: white;
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background: green; /* tab background */
 left: 0;
 top: 110%; /* extra 10% is to account for shadow dimension */
 box-shadow: -2px 2px 10px rgba(255,255,255,.5) inset;
 border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0 / 12px 12px;
 -webkit-transition: top 0.5s; /* transition property and duration */
 -moz-transition: top 0.5s;
 transition: top 0.5s;
}

ul .nav a:hover{
 color: white; 
}
ul .nav a:hover::before{
 top: 0; /* slide tab up */
}

.nav li ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;;
  width: inherit;
  margin:0px;
  text-align:center;
  }
  ul li ul li a {
  text-align:center;
 }
 .nav li:hover ul {
   display: block;
  }

  .nav li ul li {
   display: block;  
  }
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul calss="main_ul">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">HTML</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">choice 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">choice 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">choice 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a class="active" href="#">CSS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Javascript</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">choice 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">choice 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">choice 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">jQuery</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

,

Comment: also adjust width for the drop down menu with the it's dropdown tittle here is demo https://jsfiddle.net/38q2d3aw/

Comment: I really tried to understand your text, but i cant. I dont get what you want to say with this: "The problem is the background i make when mouse hover cover the tittle of the dropdown menue , and font color supposed to be white inside green background ."

Comment: sorry for not clear english not my native language , i make  green background color it appear when mouse hover the ".main_ul" this background hide the font of ".main_ul" - there code in css part under ul .nav a::before { content = " "} i do not know what should i put inside quotes.

Comment: this url may be help http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/csslibrary/item/slide_up_tabs/    i need the same navigation bar sample here but with dropdown menue under ul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of your combinators are flipped. Change "ul .nav" wherever you see it to ".nav ul" and a lot of your issues will be fixed.

You may also need to changed the z-index of the background "tab"

Add to .nav:

`z-index: 0;`

add to the .nav ul a:hover::before:

`z-index: -1;`

https://jsfiddle.net/snfe8pvj/